# Navigation in Master page asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, .net

I use this code to navigate  from master page. but its not working. 
It doesn't even show there  some is hyperlink. 
I used the same code once more. but that time it worked

any suggestions please?

```
<ul> 
      <li title="Home"><a href="Home.aspx" id="current">Home</a></li>
    <%@ Master Language="C#" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>
    **<title>Enlighten</title>
    <%--<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />--%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="images/Enlighten.css" type="text/css" />
    <%--</head>--%>
    <body>
        <%--<form id="form1" runat="server">--%>
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="logo-box">
          <h2 id="logo">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Agarwal<br />
              Dharamshala</h2>
          <h2 id="slogan">One Brick           
           <br />
           One Rupee</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="headerphoto"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="menu">
      <div class="align-left">
          <ul> 
          <li title="Home"><a href="Home.aspx" id="current">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.free-css.com/" runat="server">XXX</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://www.free-css.com/" runat="server">Donate</a></li>
          <li class="Contact"><a href="Getaccomodation.aspx" runat="server">Get </a></li>
          <li class="button"> <a href="C:\Users\Princy\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\A+D\ContactUs.aspx" runat="server">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>**
```

Comment: can you give in more code around it and the styles applied? This will help us understand what the issue is.

Comment: almost all master page code is here.

Comment: check the console .. it will show all the styles applied to it .. and check if it has been set to hide by any style

Comment: Problem has not solved :(

Comment: if so add the code to http://jsfiddle.net including the css

Comment: there is no separate css file and code is working on jsfiddle.net but not at my visual studio

Answer (score 1):

To start, view the source of the page, maybe the link is there but due to some css its not visible. If it is in the source then you know it is there you just can't see it, if it is not there you know you are actually not looking at the right page. That would be where i would start.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the code in your Master Page (inside the `ContentPlaceHolder` )  is replaced by a `Content` control on your `aspx` page.

So, check that if there is any `Content` control on your `aspx` page that has the `ContentPlaceHolderID` referring to the corresponding `ContentPlaceHolder` control in your master page

Comment: It didnt work. no content control on the page. and i tried this one. also didnt work.. pleas help<li class="button"> <a href="C:\Users\Princy\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\A+D\ContactUs.aspx" runat="server">Contact</a></li>

Comment: Are you trying to call an external site page?

Comment: No, I'm Trying to navigate page through menu bar. I saw this on web as alternative. so, Tried it.

Comment: The HREF attribute cannot work with Physical Paths. As seen in your code snippet too, you have specified Physical Paths which won't work properly. For example, you can directly Copy and Paste your Physical Path in Firefox address Bar and then Firefox will say: " The address wasn't understood. 
Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (c) isn't associated with any program."

Answer (score 0):

You have HTML before the Master page declaration, before the header and out of the body. This is probably making it impossible for the browser and/or the server to render the page...